# Visual Studio 2017 Unit Tests with C++ and C# with undiscovered C++ tests

Tags: c#, c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

With the latest Visual Studio Enterprise 15.7.2 installed cleanly, my solution unit tests work fine for my C# tests, but it acts like there are no C++ unit tests present.  Before I added the C# tests, the C++ tests worked just fine.  Is it possible to get both working?  I went the direction of a separate TestConfig.runsettings, but could not figure out how to specify native code vs. a .NET framework.  Even when I right click on the C++ unit test file to 'Run Tests' it says 'No tests found to run', despite compiling that specific .cpp project fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain your solution and projects.

Comment: Nothing special on the project, an empty solution with one static C++ library and one C# library, with a unit test project for each (native C++ and C#).  The C# one works fine (as did the C++ one before I added the C#).

Comment: What test frameworks are you using?

Comment: Only the one built into Visual Studio 2017 -- no other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your test from the "Test Explorer" and see if it detects your c++ and c# tests.

Comment: It persists in only discovering c# tests.